# Optuna hyperparameter optimization of LightGBM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, hyperparameters, lightgbm, optuna

I'm using Optuna to tune the hyperparameters of a LightGBM model. I suggested values for a few hyperparameters to optimize (using `trail.suggest_int` / `trial.suggest_float` / `trial.suggest_loguniform`).

There are also some hyperparameters for which I set a fixed value. For example I set `feature_fraction = 1`. However, when I ran my code, I saw that Optuna was trying to test different `feature_fraction` values. This is not what I want because it takes too much time. I don't understand why.

Code:

```
def objective(trial):   
    param = {
            'objective': 'binary',
            'boosting': 'gbdt', 
            'metric': 'auc', 
            'max_depth':4,
            'seed': 100,
            'feature_fraction': 1,
            'feature_fraction_seed': 100,
            'is_unbalance': True,
            'is_provide_training_metric': True, 
            'extra_trees': True,
            'force_col_wise': True, 
            'numleaves': trial.suggest_int('num_leaves', 10, 30),
            'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 1e-4, 1e-2), 
            'min_data_in_leaf': trial.suggest_int('min_data_in_leaf', 10, 80),
            'min_sum_hessianin_leaf':trial.suggest_loguniform('min_sum_hessian_in_leaf', 1e-8, 10.0),
            'verbose': trial.suggest_int('verbose', 1, 5), 
            'max_bin': trial.suggest_int('max_bin', 80, 300),
            'lambda_l1': trial.suggest_loguniform('lambda_l1', 1e-5, 1e-1), 
            'path_smooth':trial.suggest_uniform('path_smooth', 0.4, 1.5)}

    threshold = 0.5

    gbm=lgb.train(param,
                  train_set=1gbtrain,
                  valid_sets=[1gb_val,lgb_train],
                  valid_names = ['eval', 'train'], 
                  verbose_eval=2,
                  early_stopping_rounds=5, 
                  num_boost_round=10)

     y_pred=gbm.predict(X_test)
     pred_labels =(y_pred > threshold).astype(int)
     accuracy=sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, pred_labels) 
     return accuracy

study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=5, show_progress_bar = True, gc_after_trial=True)
print('Number of finished trials:', len(study.trials)) 
print('Best trial:', study.best_trial.params)
```

Output:
[image: log shows it was trying to test different feature_fraction]

Answer (score 2):

While I do not know the reason why optuna tries different values for `feature_fraction`, you could try to set the default value like

`'feature_fraction': trial.suggest_int('feature_fraction', 1, 1)`